# NodeJS App Rendering View Without Data Until Refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First off, I'm new to Javascript and I'm a hobbyist when it comes to scripting.  That being said, there may be some very noob things I'm doing that's causing this issue.  I'm building a NodeJS app with Express and MongoDB.  I'm using ejs as my view engine along with a Bootstrap 4 template.  Here's my issue:

routes.js is used for the express routes.  Here's an example of one of the routes:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var indexData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    updateIndexData((docs) => {
      return resolve(docs);
    });
  }); 

  indexData.then(function(values) {
    res.render('index', {
      data: values
    });
  });
});
```

To give a brief summary, when the user points the browser to localhost:port, the .get function calls the updateIndexData() function, which all it does gather the necessary data using Mongoose find() query.  Then, since it's setup as a Promise, once that completes, it passes the data to the ejs view, which displays the data in browser.  The data is updated every 5 minutes through API calls to a server, so I need to be able to call the new data on the fly.

The problem I'm having is this:  the code works.  It displays the data exactly how I want... but only after I refresh the browser.  On initial load, the view renders, but the data is completely missing.  It's almost as if the view is being rendered before the data is finished compiling, but my understanding of Promises is that this shouldn't happen.  Any help from the community would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You're right the res.render function will only run when the promise resolves. But have you checked the returned data of the "updateIndexData" function? The behavior you described can easily happen if the updateIndexData function returns an empty string or undefined ...